# TabView with PageTabViewStyle on tvOS navigationlink or buttons not working

Tags: swiftui, tvos

Neither navigation or Button's actions working in the pages of the TabView with PageTabViewStyle. Anybody has any ideas or workarounds? Repro code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Button(action: {
                print("First selected")
            }){
                Text("Fist")
            }
            .tag(0)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()
            Button(action: {
                print("Second selected")
            }){
                Text("Second").tag(1)
            }
            .tag(1)
            Button(action: {
                print("Third selected")
            }){
                Text("Third")
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .frame(width: 900, height: 400)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: how about put your button inside a VStack

Answer (score 0):

Button action is working in your shared code but the issue is with the tappable area of Button, which is very less.
Hence, you are unable to sense the button action.

Increase the Button tappable area like this :

```
Text("Fist")
      .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
      .background(Color.red)
```